# Object oriented CSS

Tags: html, css, oop, oocss

I watched this [presentation about object oriented css](http://www.slideshare.net/stubbornella/object-oriented-css), but I think I either don't understand it correctly or don't understand the benefits of using OO CSS:

Example HTML:

```
<div class="border-1 bg-2 color-1 font-1">
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
/* borders */
.border-1 { border: 1px solid red; }

/* backgrounds: */
.bg-2 { background: yellow; }

/* other sections */
```

I see an advantage in being able to change styles for multiple elements quickly, for instance, being able to switch the color scheme would be very useful.

But actually, you're defining the style/look inside the HTML, or at least a part of it. Of course, it's better than using the `style` attribute, because you still are able to exchange the styles for a set of groups.

The point is, you are defining the style-groups inside the HTML, but I learned that you should create "logical" groups inside the HTML (e.g. `class="nav-item"` / `class="btn submit-btn"`) and the CSS completely applies the style and defines which elements belong together from the "stylistic" point of view (e.g. `.nav-item, .submit-btn { background: red; }`).

Maybe I totally misunderstood the concept. However, I still don't know a good way of constructing my CSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CSS isn't object oriented. My suggestion is to forget what you've read about "object oriented CSS" and instead focus on the problems with CSS you're trying to solve. If they are to make CSS easier to write, read and maintain, or to get more features (like CSS variables) I think [Less](http://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/) will suit your need much better.

Using CSS like what's suggested with "object oriented CSS" just leads to terrible, non-semantic and meaningless CSS that in the long run isn't any easier to maintain than "ordinary" CSS. Both `id` and `class` should have [semantic and meaningful names](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames), so using a framework that allows you to write semantic CSS (that describes intent instead of presentation) is in my humble opinion much better.

Comment: @madr, have you tried [Less](http://lesscss.org/) or [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/)? They are a much better solution to the problem than trying to shoe-horn object-orientation into something that is and never will be object-oriented.

Comment: @asbjomu Since there is no reason not to, I combine preprocessors with OOCSS to get the best from them both. My teams are really pleased with this working agreement.

Comment: @AsbjørnUlsberg , speaking of my experience , for a UI dev moving to scss/sass with no knowledge of OOCSS , is going to be of very little good , the main reason being OOCSS makes a dev think when should he abstract a certain portion of CSS as a standalone component and if your not asking yourself this question as a CSS dev , then moving on to SCSS is not going to do the person any good ! this reason alone can save alot of code bloat !!

Answer (score 3):

This is more of a "name dropping", that an actual method.
The code that you have shown is often derogatory called "[enterprise css](http://enterprise-css.com/3)", there is no excuse for it.

More over, having multiple classes on elements actually hurts performance.

I advice you to adhere to [Mozilla's guidelines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Writing_Efficient_CSS) when making your CSS, which works same for other browsers, too.
And make dedicated .css file with hacks for IE6, 7 and 8.

Comment: Please refer to a section which tells multiple classes are considered bad due performance. Using long and unnecessary complicated CSS selectors is AFAIK far worse than using multiple classes. http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/03/27/reflows-repaints-css-performance-making-your-javascript-slow/

Comment: `Avoid descendent selector, IDs, element refs, !important. Use CSS Lint and CSS grids`. this is OOCSS ? ok. fine. nothing wrong with it. Pretty much common wisdom. But where is the "Object-Oriented" part ?  _Programming techniques may include features such as data abstraction, encapsulation, messaging, modularity, polymorphism, and inheritance._ [(c) wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) How are you supposed to encapsulate anything in CSS ? .. CSS does not even have variables, and `<style scoped>` is far from becoming production ready (even with shim).

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that you reuse the same css classes on many elements. This both saves on writing css and on maintaining css. so instead of defining `.create-button` `.cancel-button` `.create-and-new` button you would just have a `.button` that defines padding, `size`, `background`, `color`, `line-height`, `font-size`, `font-family` and `font-weight`. And some really small classes for the different button styles like to change the `color` or `font-size`

a proper oocss project I often still use can be found here: https://github.com/stubbornella/oocss/wiki

but yes you should have a look at less, it combines the easy of reusing the same css properties on multiple elements with proper class names.

Answer (score 1):

"Object-oriented CSS" is really just a design pattern for how to get most out of your CSS and is basicly the same approach Jonathan Snooks calls [**SMACSS**](http://smacss.com/).

Whether you call it OOCSS or SMACSS, the key to the approach is that you create generic UI elements like the [**nav abstraction**](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/the-nav-abstraction/). These UI elements can then be enhanced with more specific features by adding extra classes to the element and/or a container element. Or, as an alternative, you can add your own custom CSS rules using the element's ID or semantic classes.

Further reading :

- [**An Introduction To Object Oriented CSS (OOCSS)**](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/12/an-introduction-to-object-oriented-css-oocss/)
- [**OOCSS + Sass = The best way to CSS**](http://ianstormtaylor.com/oocss-plus-sass-is-the-best-way-to-css/)